# Setting automationIDs for dataitems in a WPF Grid for automation with UI Automation Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I've got an application that's written in C# using .NET Framework 3.5 and want to automate the UI using Microsoft UI Automation Framework. I'm not allowed to show everything here, because it's a software from my company.

In this application I'm generating a grid that displays my data items.

I've tried to set the automationIDs for every data item in the grid through XAML, but the problem is, that I can't see the dataitems there. They are dynamically generated during runtime of my application. Only the grid that contains the data items is defined in the XAML. I will post a snippet of my XAML below.

I've also tried to set the automationIDs through the Code of the program, but I only managed to get the AutomationElement of every data item. There I'm stuck. I don't know how to set the automationIds for every AutomationElement there.

To sum it up I am either looking for:

- Setting the automationID for data items in a WPF grid through XAML
- Setting the automationID for data item AutomationElement through Code

Screenshot of my Inspect Tool:
[Inspect Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0LnW.jpg)

Snippet of my XAML Code:

```
    <ListView IsEnabled="{Binding TestSelectorEnabled}" x:Name="ListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding TestsViewModel.TestsDataTable}" SelectedValue="{Binding TestsViewModel.SelectedTest}" SelectedValuePath="TestName" Height="180" View="{Binding TestsViewModel.GridView}"  TabIndex="0" MinWidth="1" Focusable="False"/>
            <Grid  Visibility="Collapsed" IsSharedSizeScope="False">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify **ItemTemplate** explicitly, it will let you set ids.
It should be an automation API to iterate though ListView children as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Viktor Syromiatnikov this got me on the right track. I now managed to set a static automationId for every ListViewItem.

Does anyone know how I can set the automationID dynamic for every ListViewItem so it looks like dataitem1, dataitem2, dataitem3 for every new ListViewItem?

My XAML looks like this now:

```
<ListView IsEnabled="{Binding TestSelectorEnabled}" x:Name="ListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding TestsViewModel.TestsDataTable}" SelectedValue="{Binding TestsViewModel.SelectedTest}" SelectedValuePath="TestName" Height="180" View="{Binding TestsViewModel.GridView}"  TabIndex="0" MinWidth="1" Focusable="False">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="dataitem"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: I guess, to have a kind of dynamic value in `AutomationProperties.AutomationId` you could bind this property to the model items, but I doubt such approach fits nicely into MVVM :)